# reloading page every time i visit different page in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flask-restful

I have made 2 bottom navigation bar and on every page, I am hitting Flask API for getting data from database. the problem occurs after starting the app I switch between tabs. after switching, the card disappears on there own, and to get the data again I have to go and refresh that particular page. I don't know the problem as no error is shown.
can anyone tell me how to solve this problem so that the data remains even if I switch that Tab?